# Multi-Line Regular Expression

Tags: regex, perl, ultraedit

I'm trying to match out of this text:

```
<a href="http://english317.ning.com/profiles/blogs/bad-business-writing-487">Continue</a>
                                      </div>
                <p class="small">

                                                    Added by <a href="/profile/KemberleyRamirez">Kemberley Ramirez</a> on September 2, 2010 at 11:38pm
```

I'd like to get the text after /blogs (e.g. "bad-business-writing-487") and also the added by string (Student Name and submit date) (e.g. "Kemberley Ramirez on September 2, 2010 at 11:38pm")

I'm using UltraEdit with Perl expressions.

Comment: You might find this site useful: regexlib.com/

Comment: [Friends don't let friends parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I didn't ask if I should; I asked HOW TO. And it's perfectly feasible in this situation with the fact that the tags are routinely in the same place to parse it with REGEX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to match, but you are better off using a proper HTML parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(\*DATA);

my $blog_re = qr{^http://english317.ning.com/profiles/blogs/(.+)\z};
my $profile_re = qr{^/profile/(\w+)\z};

while ( my $tag = $parser->get_tag('a') ) {
    next unless my ($href) = $tag->get_attr('href');
    if ( $href =~ $blog_re or $href =~ $profile_re ) {
        print "[$1]\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<a href="http://english317.ning.com/profiles/blogs/bad-business-writing-487">Continue</a>
                                      </div>
                <p class="small">

                                                    Added by <a href="/profile/KemberleyRamirez">Kemberley Ramirez</a> on September 2, 2010 at 11:38pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerGrep in "dot matches newline" mode, I came up with this:

```
(?>profiles/blogs/(.*?)").*?added by(.*?)</a>(.*?2010.*?\d{2}[ap]m)
```

(and then an extra processing search)
    `<`?a.*?>

Answer (score -1):

The /s and /m modifiers control how multiple lines are handled.
see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

You probably want something like rrr reg.exps with the /s modifier, or something like this: (untested)

```
$foo =~ m|blogs/([^"]+).*Added by <[^>]+>([^<]+)</a>|s
```

Using m|| instead of // to avoid all the escaping ..

Answer (score -2):

Following should work for multiple lines:

```
.*blogs\/(\S+)".*\(\n.*\)*<a.*>(.*)<\/a>(.*)
```